# Как разделить число на разряды в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, который производит вычисления и выводит результат.

```
rez = Math.round(numb*pay*2.1/100);
$(".result p span").text(rez);
```

Задача разбить выводимое число по разрядам, т.е. вместо 1000000 выводить 1 000 000.

Пробую такой вариант:

```
rez = Math.round(numb*pay*2.1/100);
var outrez = rez.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
$(".result p span").text(outrez);
```

Но результата нет вообще никакого. 
Подскажите как исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, .toLocaleString('ru') сделало работу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 30):

Попробуйте так:

```
(1000000).toLocaleString('ru')
```

Answer (score 5):

Код с регулярным выражением тоже работает.
Ошибка заключается в том, что [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) - возвращает число, а у числа нет метода `replace`, он есть у строки. Поэтому число надо просто привести к строке.

```js
var numb = 10572,
    pay = 11073;
rez = Math.round(numb*pay*2.1/100);
var outrez = (rez+'').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');

document.body.innerHTML = outrez;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один рабочий вариант:

```js
Number.prototype.toDivide = function() {
 var int = String(Math.trunc(this));
 if(int.length <= 3) return int;
 var space = 0;
 var number = '';

 for(var i = int.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(space == 3) {
   number = ' ' + number;
   space = 0;
  }
  number = int.charAt(i) + number;
  space++;
 }

 return number;
}

var test0 = 1;
var test1 = 12;
var test2 = 123;
var test3 = 1234;
var test4 = 12345;
var test5 = 123456;
var test6 = 1234567;
var test7 = 12345678;
var test8 = 123456789;
var test9 = 1234567890;
console.log(test0.toDivide()); //1
console.log(test1.toDivide()); //12
console.log(test2.toDivide()); //123
console.log(test3.toDivide()); //1 234
console.log(test4.toDivide()); //12 345
console.log(test5.toDivide()); //123 456
console.log(test6.toDivide()); //1 234 567
console.log(test7.toDivide()); //12 345 678
console.log(test8.toDivide()); //123 456 789
console.log(test9.toDivide()); //1 234 567 890
```

Из плюсов: работает сразу для всех чисел, которые когда либо будут созданы, и можно подтачивать под свои вкусы)))