# Поставить точки в больших числах

Tags: javascript

Получаю например число 1000000 или 10000 или любое другое. Как можно их преобразовываться отделяю по 3 знака с конца точкой.

Например `1000000 => 1.000.000` или `10000 => 10.000`

Comment: Вдруг,кому пригодится
`result = 1000000;

result += "";

result = result.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1.')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var a = 1000000;
console.log(a);
console.log(a.toString());
console.log(a.toLocaleString());
```