# Разделить тысячные знаки пробелом

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт который каждый день прибавляет по числу на сайте - скажите пожалуйста как сделать так что бы тысячные разделялись пробелом?

```html
<div class="hron8889">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    d0 = new Date(1989, 0, 1);
    d1 = new Date();
    dt = (d1.getTime() - d0.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);

    document.write(
      'Текст <strong class="hronos6664">'
        + Math.round(dt)
        + '</strong> текст'
    );
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: @Doofy а пример кода не могли бы скинуть? Я не шарю в этом поэтому и написала сюда.

Comment: Татьяна, собираю сервер в дискорде с начинающими программистами, там мы помогаем друг другу. Если есть вопросы, контакты указаны у меня в профиле. А этот сайт служит как база знаний, а не помощи другим

Comment: Поэтому этот вопрос был закрыт и помечен как дубликат. На него уже давали ответ и смысла во втором таком же вопросе нет

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из вопроса, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под словом "тысячные"

Предполагаю, что вы хотели бы разделить округленное число на разряды

Посмотрите ответы по [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-javascript) ссылке

Если правильно понял, о чем речь

```js
let d0 = new Date(1989, 0, 1);
let d1 = new Date();
let dt = (d1.getTime() - d0.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);

// 11 636
// let res = Math.round(dt).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

// 11 636,485
// let res = dt.toLocaleString('ru')

// 11 636
let res = Math.round(dt).toLocaleString('ru')

console.log( 'Оригинал dt', dt )


document.querySelector('.hron8889').innerHTML = `Текст <strong class="hronos6664">${res}</strong> текст`;
```

```html
<div class="hron8889"></div>
```

Вариант такой, как вы задали в вопросе (должно выглядеть так):

```
<div class="hron8889"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
let d0 = new Date(1989, 0, 1);
let d1 = new Date();
let dt = (d1.getTime() - d0.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);

// 11 636
// let res = Math.round(dt).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

// 11 636,485
// let res = dt.toLocaleString('ru')

// 11 636
let res = Math.round(dt).toLocaleString('ru')

// console.log( 'Оригинал dt', dt )

document.querySelector('.hron8889').innerHTML = `Текст <strong class="hronos6664">${res}</strong> текст`;
</script>
```

Comment: Да я и имела ввиду это, только я беру Ваш код вставляю и страница вообще не грузится(

Comment: @ТатьянаТегин вероятно вы что-то делаете неправильно. код из моего ответа работает, вы можете проверить это, нажав на кнопку "Выполнить код". перейдите по [ссылке на codepen](https://codepen.io/pogorelove/pen/Pozxqwd) и сделайте следующее: в самом низу экрана найти слово Export, кликнуть по нему, кликнуть Export .zip, скачать zip файл, разархивировать его в любое место, перейти в разархивированную папку, в ней будет папка dist, в папке dist открыть файл index.html в браузере, код также будет работать. в данном случае в папке dist будет два файла index.html (html код) и script.js (js код)

Comment: в данном случае вам нужно научиться правильно подключать/использовать js код, потому что ctrl+c + ctrl+v не всегда работает так, как вы можете ожидать

Comment: @ТатьянаТегин попробуйте разместить <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> под <div class="hron8889"></div>, upd: обновил ответ, попробуйте, может так будет понятнее

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
d0 = new Date(1989,0,1);
 d1 = new Date();
 dt = Math.round(d1.getTime() - d0.getTime()/ (1000*60*60*24*1));     
 document.write('Текст форматированный <strong class="hronos6664">' + dt.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ") + '</strong> текст');
 
 
 document.write('<br/>Текст оригинал<strong class="hronos6664">' + dt.toString() + '</strong> текст');
```

```html
<div class="hron8889"></div>
```

Comment: Появляются какие-то непонятные значения - пробелы стоят, да. Однако сам скрипт не работает уже как надо(