# Помогите разбить число на разряды javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется такой скрипт, в конце функция разделения на разряды, но ни в какую не разделяет...

```js
var wasUsed = false;

function doCalc(){
    
    var meterPlus = 0;
    var totalMaterial = 0;
    var totalWorks = 0;
    var userInputSquare = $('#square').val();
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){meterPlus = 4155.42;}else{meterPlus = 2849.11;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 0){meterPlus = 0;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){totalMaterial = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*72/100;}else{totalMaterial = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*28/100;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){totalWorks = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*28/100;}else{totalWorks = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*72/100;}
    var totalPrice = userInputSquare*meterPlus;
    
    $('#meter').html(meterPlus);
    $('#material').html(totalMaterial);
    $('#works').html(totalWorks);
    $('#calcPrice').html(totalPrice);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice', function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
        if($(this).val() > 9999) { $(this).val(1); }
        doCalc();
    });


    $("input[name=texture]:radio").change(function () {
        doCalc();
    });
    
    wasUsed = true; // init calc while not sending Yandex Goal
    doCalc();       
    wasUsed = false;
    
});


function digits_int(target){
    val = $(target).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    val = val.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
    $(target).val(val);
}
 
$(function($){
    $('#calcForm').on('textarea', 'input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice', function(e){
        digits_int(this);
    });
    digits_int('textarea', 'input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice');
});
```

И HTML:

```html
<div class="configurator" id="calcForm">
                    <div id="question-1" class="question">
                    <p><strong class="red">Введите площадь пола (м<sup>2</sup>)</strong></p>
                    <input class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" type="number" id="square" name="square" value="0"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="question-2" class="question">
                    <p>Стоимость руб./м<sup>2</sup>:</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="meter" name="meter"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="question-3" class="question">
                    <p>Стоимость материалов (руб.):</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="material" name="material"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="question-4" class="question">
                    <p>Стоимость работ (руб.):</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="works" name="works"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="question-5" class="question">
                    <p>Общая стоимость (руб.):</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control bb-red mb-3 registration-input-box" id="calcPrice" name="calcPrice"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка, уже пару дней бьюсь...

Comment: [Как разделить число на разряды в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499397/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b2-javascript?rq=1) - Похоже это то, что вам надо

Answer (score 0):

не пробовал использовать Math.round()?
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Я новичок, только в html пока шарю) как это можно на моем примере применить?